# Umbraco incorrect 'Link to document' when setting hostname

Tags: url, hyperlink, document, umbraco

Basically defined a domain (Manage hostnames option) for Node1 and have Umbraco tree structure

```
Content
     + en
       + Node1
        + Subnode1
        + Subnode2
       + Node2
     + es
       + Node3
        …
```

When check ‘Subnode1’ properties have that ‘Link to document’ and ‘Alternative Links’ path are inconsistent:

```
Link to document: /Node1/subnode1.aspx
Alternative Links: http://www.domain.com/subnode1.aspx
```

I would like to get rid of the folder ‘/Node1/’ in ‘Link to document’, that is returned in NiceUrl and is messing my Url links on pages.

I would like to only have:

```
Link to document: /subnode1.aspx
Alternative Links: http://www.domain.com/subnode1.aspx
```

Tried to follow steps in
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/3505-Change-site-root-node,-NiceUrl-doesnt-change
but no luck the only thing I get is:

```
Page not found
    umbraco tried this to match it using this xpath query'/domainprefixes-are-used-so-i-do-not-work')
    This page can be replaced with a custom 404 page
```

Hope I get some helpful reply :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the solution here:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/5481-niceurl--3rd-level

Also, did you try to republish the entire site?

Comment: Thanks for replying azzlack. Was in a hurry so had to implement a work around for my project. Solution you suggest seems complicated but difficult to understand when is so badly formated :(almost useless). Somebody else suggested to use [Umbraco property umbracoUrlName](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlname) but this not solve the problem since want to remove the full folder from the Url.