# Umbraco Alternative Links doesn't work

Tags: umbraco

Hello I created some page in Umbraco 4.7 CMS,
configure some alternative links to page(section) it looks like.
If I look at

Link to document
/folder/folder2/page1.aspx - ***workig***

Alternative Links

1. http://site.com/folder/folder2/page1.aspx - ***workig***
2. http://site.com/en/folder/folder2/page1.aspx - **not working**
3. http://site.com/old-folder/folder2/page1.aspx - **not working**

but in browser just  /folder/folder2/page1.aspx show a valid page other links redirect users to 404 page that configured in umbraco config file.

Comment: Although I don't know much else to suggest other than "did you try republishing?". You might find some useful information [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325402/assigning-hostnames-in-umbraco) and [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043348/umbraco-incorrect-link-to-document-when-setting-hostname).

Comment: Do you have links #2 and #3 configured as aliases?

Comment: ProNotion what do you mean ? How I can configuration it ?

Comment: @cleric How would Umbraco know that the urls #2 and #3 map to that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the UrlRewriting module to get this working. You could add a new rule similar to the following:

```
<add name="page1rewrite"
                virtualUrl="^~/en/folder/folder2/page1.aspx"
                rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
                destinationUrl="~/folder/folder2/page2.aspx"
                ignoreCase="true" />
```

This could be further improved depending on your exact requirements but you could it you wanted rewrite all urls ~/en/folder/folder2/ to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option would be to use the [umbracoUrlAlias](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlalias) document type property.